# Underfull \hbox with \input

Tags: input, badness

Consider the following (minimal) example:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\parindent0em    
\begin{document}
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.1em}
    %\input{file}
\end{document}
```

It works well so far. But now, I have a file called "file.tex" which contains exactly the same, that is to say only `\rule{\textwidth}{0.1em}`. When running

```
\documentclass{article}    
\parindent0em    
\begin{document}
    %\rule{\textwidth}{0.1em}
    \input{file}
\end{document}
```

I get an underfull \hbox. Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The input is equivalent to

```
\documentclass{article}    
\parindent0em    
\begin{document}
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.1em} {} 

\end{document}
```

which has two space tokens at the end of a paragraph so produces a spurious extra underfull line.

---

If you add `\showoutput` then you see that the above makes a two line paragraph

line one, a 0pt wide indentation box, a box with the rule and 0pt \rightskip

```
...\hbox(1.00006+0.0)x345.0
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
....\hbox(1.00006+0.0)x345.0
.....\rule(1.00006+0.0)x345.0
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
```

Then baseline spacing

```
...\penalty 300
...\glue(\baselineskip) 12.0
```

Then a second line that just has  0pt `\rightskip` it managed to drop both the glue from the spaces and the glue from `\parfillskip` so it is infinitely underfull reported as badness 10000

```
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
```

Comment: Does it mean that `\input{foo}` is the same as `[content of foo] {}`? How did you find out?

Comment: @Thrash you have a space (newline) after the rule and a space (newline) after the input{} so you have two spaces add `%` to the ends of lines and the problem will go

Comment: how did I find out?, er well I've used tex since 1987 so there are not that many surprises:-) I'll add a bit more info to my answer...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I don't understand it completely. In my file there is no extra space after the command and it consists of one line. The last character is `}`. Do you mean the line break to `\end{document}`?

Comment: @Thrash yes, you most likely have a linebreak after the `\rule{}` inside the file and you have a linebreak after `\input{}` in the main file

Comment: (@Thrash)  I think that a `\showlists` in horizontal mode is even more enlightening than `\showoutput`: it will show very clearly the two spaces after the rule, only one of which is removed by the `\par` implied by `\end{document}`.

Comment: @GuM yes perhaps, you are right. although showoutput is pretty much always the first thing I add to a user supplied MWE:-)

Comment: `\showlists` produces an error. Where do I have to put it?

Comment: @Thrash: It’s ***not*** an error (even if it interrupts compilation as if it were), but simply a diagnostic message: just hit <return> and then look in the `.log` file.  After all, D.C. might have been right not to suggest it! (;-)  **Edit:** You should insert a line that says `\showboxbreadth=1000 \showboxdepth=10 \showlists` between the `\input{file}` line and the `\end{document}` one.